# Javascript assign property from function

Tags: javascript

I don't know if this is possible, but what I'd like to accomplish is assign a property value to an object from a function that is called. When the function for `active` is ran, I'd like to assign either a true or false as its value as the object is being created. Can we use self-executing functions in this way?

Here's my code, still in-progress, but is there something of this sort that is accomplish able in javascript?

```
        graphObj.list.push({
            name: graphData[i].name,
            value: Math.floor(graphData[i].time / graphData[graphData.length - 1] * 100),
            str: graphData[i].strTime
            active: (function(){
                if (activeActivityName != "" && graphData[i].name == activeActivityName){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: This is not a self-invoking function. You would need `()` at the end for it to be immediately executed.

Comment: Adding a `()` causes a syntax error, it appears as that isn't the proper syntax if this is possible

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/s2kwn2h3/

Comment: Oh, you're missing a comma after `strTime`.

Answer (score 2):

I really want to discourage you from using the IIFE here since I strongly believe this is an inappropriate use of IIFE. So how about just assigning the result of the condition:

```
graphObj.list.push({
    name: graphData[i].name,
    value: Math.floor(graphData[i].time / graphData[graphData.length - 1] * 100),
    str: graphData[i].strTime,
    active: (activeActivityName != "" && graphData[i].name == activeActivityName)
});
```

Comment: I do like this approach!

Answer (score 0):

Why go down the path of using an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression when you could just call a function.

```
function isActive(activeActivityName, graphData, i) {
    if (activeActivityName != "" && graphData[i].name == activeActivityName) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

graphObj.list.push({
    name: graphData[i].name,
    value: Math.floor(graphData[i].time / graphData[graphData.length - 1] * 100),
    str: graphData[i].strTime,
    active: isActive(activeActivityName, graphData, i)
});
```

Comment: I know I'm only going to be using the function in one place, so I thought an IIFE would be best here. Your example is also fine

Comment: An anonymous function _is_ fine in that case... so long as it doesn't overcomplicate your code.

Comment: That is something of a matter of opinion. Consider this rebuttal. http://toddmotto.com/avoiding-anonymous-javascript-functions/